# How to get a list of invalidated procedures and functions in a HANA database?

Tags: hana

**I want to get a list of invalidated procedures and functions in a schema in HANA. Is there an easy way to do that?**

Detailed problem:
I had to delete a column in a table (OWHS.Col1). All its references, joins, etc are to be replaced by another one (OLCT.Col2): E.g.

```
SELECT T1.Dummy FROM INV1 T1 INNER JOIN OWHS W1 ON T1.Col = W1.Col1
```

replaced by

```
SELECT T1.Dummy FROM INV1 T1 INNER JOIN OLCT L1 ON T1.Col = L1.Col2
```

The above example is just illustrative.

I have changed as many references as I could think of but want to verify that OWHS.Col1 is not lying anywhere in any procedure/function. Since the column is deleted now, those procedures/functions must have been invalidated. Is there a way to get a list of invalidated procedures and functions in the entire schema?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the question answered on the SAP forum:

```
SELECT * FROM PROCEDURES WHERE IS_VALID = 'FALSE';
SELECT * FROM FUNCTIONS WHERE IS_VALID = 'FALSE';
```